# What exactly does なにか mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

So I read this, [What does なにか mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52861/what-does-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8b-mean-in-this-sentence) and to clarify, I also ran across a sentence, "何かプレゼントを買いましょうか? Here, I'm guessing 何か does not mean something, or at least I think, so does the sentence mean like, "Lets go buy some kind of present?" or

Could it be, "lets go buy some presents?"

Answer (score 1):

明鏡国語辞典 does not explicitly explain the part of speech of this type of 何か. It just says it's a "phrase" (連語). Rather than worrying about the direct English translation of this type of 何か, I think you just can remember this pattern and go on. This pattern is translated into English in slightly different ways depending on the surrounding context, and I hesitate to conclusively say it's "some", "something", "any" or "anything" in English.

- 何か特別なこと: something/anything special
- 何か食べるもの: something/anything to eat
- 何かプレゼント: some present
- 何か棒のようなもの: something like a stick
- 誰か強い人: someone/anyone strong
- 誰か料理人: some/any chef
- どこか静かな場所: some quiet place

Related: [Is 「だれか素敵な人に...」 an example of apposition?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87160/5010)